# Как избавиться от выделения фокуса в JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scene-builder

В SceneBuilder отменила фокус убрав галочку в Focus Traversable.
Но когда запускаю программу и нажимаю на TextField, чтобы что-то написать, появляется фокус. Может что-то в стилях написать?

Comment: Где ваш код? Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.